How to extract a substring from a column in a dataframe based in the column from another dataFrame?
I have found a solution from my problem, but it is clearly the most dumb and inefficient one. I was hoping that someone could help me with a proper solution.
I have two data frames containing a column with a telephone number. df1["telephone"] can have one or more numbers separated by commas and df2["telephone"] has only single numbers:
df1["telephone"]

telephone

115879878
411564656
465464654,45646546
464665465,46456465,87972315
123165648


df2["telephone"]

telephone

156465456
132131321
879878999
456489798
546489798
465478978

What I want to do is, check if one of the numbers in df1["telephone"] is in df2["telefone"] and create a column with the matched number.
I have managed to do this using the following code:
df1['telephone'] = df1['telephone'].astype(str)
df2["telephone"] = df2["telephone"].astype(str)

telephone_match = []

for telephone_1 in df1['telephone']:
  telephone_found = False

  for telephone_2 in df2["telephone"]:

    if (telephone_2 in telephone_1):
      telephone_match.append(telephone_2)
      telephone_found = True
      continue
    
  if (not telephone_found):
    telephone_match.append(False)

df1['matches'] = telephone_match

This works, but it takes ages to run. I pretty sure it is the dumbest possible method, but I have no idea how to do this efficiently. Can someone please help me?

Consider str.split and explode to flatten the multiple comma-separated items on separate lines (where all other columns repeat), then merge to second data frame on telephone column:
df3 = (
    df1.assign(telephone = lambda x: x["telephone"].str.split(','))
       .explode("telephone")
       .merge(df2.assign(matched = True), on="telephone", how="left")
)

In case you need to retain original df1 structure, de-dupe above result by some unique identifier and new match columns, then merge back to original data frame:
df3 = (
    df3.reindex(["unique_id", "match"], axis="columns")
       .drop_duplicates()
)

df1 = df1.merge(df3, on="unique_id", how="left")



You can define a function _find() and then apply() it to df1["telephone"]:

You can use set() to remove duplicates.


import pandas as pd


def _find(nums):
    res = [num.strip() for num in nums.split(',')]
    matches = [num for num in res if num in sdf2]
    return matches[0] if matches else None


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "telephone": ["115879878", "411564656", "465464654,45646546", "464665465,46456465,87972315", "123165648"]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "telephone": ["156465456", "132131321", "879878999", "456489798", "546489798", "465478978", "115879878"]
})

sdf2 = set(df2["telephone"])
df1["matches"] = df1["telephone"].apply(_find)

print(df1)


Prints
                     telephone    matches
0                    115879878  115879878
1                    411564656       None
2           465464654,45646546       None
3  464665465,46456465,87972315       None
4                    123165648       None


You can make it a bit more efficient by using generators:
import pandas as pd

def _find(nums):
    gen = map(str.strip, nums.split(','))
    return next((num for num in gen if num in sdf2), None)


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "telephone": ["115879878", "411564656", "465464654,45646546", "464665465,46456465,87972315", "123165648"]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "telephone": ["156465456", "132131321", "879878999", "456489798", "546489798", "465478978", "115879878"]
})

sdf2 = set(df2["telephone"])
df1["matches"] = df1["telephone"].apply(_find)

print(df1)



Another possible solution, which starts by concatenating the two dataframes, subsequently finds the duplicates (which are the matches) and finally drops the duplicates:
d = pd.concat([df1['telephone'].str.split(',').explode(), df2])
d.assign(matched = d.duplicated()).drop_duplicates(subset='telephone', keep='last')

Output:
   telephone  matched
1  411564656    False
2  465464654    False
2   45646546    False
3  464665465    False
3   46456465    False
3   87972315    False
4  123165648    False
0  156465456    False
1  132131321    False
2  879878999    False
3  456489798    False
4  546489798    False
5  465478978    False
6  115879878     True


Here is one-line approach:
df1["matches"] = df1['telephone'].str.split(',').explode().isin(df2['telephone']).groupby(level=0).agg(sum).astype(bool)

It assumes that "telephone" column type is string, as in your example. The idea is to separate each number split(','), then flatten explode(), then find occurrence isin(), then group back the results by index.
